# ajax updating div tag is flickering

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I just have a simple ajax function that loads on the screen in a div tag when the page is loaded and keeps updating periodicily.  But for some reason it keeps flickering.  What is wrong?

```
    function callStatus(){  

        $("#imgs").load("statusRetrieve.php");
        setInterval( "callStatus()", 5000 );
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `setInterval()` out of the function

Answer (score 0):

One issue may be that, as written, each time `callStatus()` is fired, a new interval is *created* (not *replaced*).  Consider replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

Alternatively, consider moving your `setInterval` outside of the function, then calling your function elsewhere in code.  It can also be handy to store your interval to a variable, in the event you want to clear the interval:

```
var callStatusInterval = setInterval(callStatus, 5000);
// ... 
clearInterval(callStatusInterval);
```

Comment: I need to get better at loading comments before posting.  :)  But hey, I did  mention `setTimeout` too, so a smidge different!

Comment: Thanks for replying, I did as you suggested and it got better.  However it still flickers from time to time.  Is this the best I can get it or is there a better way?